# How to declare unique users in R+Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

For debugging purposes, I'd like to log in to my shiny app as user1, user2, ..., user6. I have tried 2 methods without success. Getting any method working be good, and getting all working would be great.

## Preferred Method

Declare user from url inside server.R and access outside of `observe`

In Web-Browser
http://127.0.0.1:XXXX?username=JA1

server.R

```
user <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)[['username']]

## Outside of any function  ->
cat( file=stderr(), "User: ", user, "\n")
```

## 2nd Method

How do turn url parameters into R variables in shiny? This is similar to https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/url-inputs ,but I would prefer to use the new variable outside of an observer (see above)

server.R

```
shinyServer( function( input, output, session){    
observe({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    if (!is.null(query[['user']])) {
        ## The New User [declared in the URL]
        user <- query[['user']]
    } else {
        ## The Default User    
        user <- "user1"
    }
})

## Some Code that executes based on `user`
if(user=="user3") cat( file=stderr(), user, " Working Now\n")
```

## 3rd Method

How to have each user log in with a sequentially assigned ID?

server.R

```
## Global Reactives to Count Sequential Users
Debug <- reactiveValues(UserCount=6)


shinyServer( function( input, output, session){
observe(Debug$userCount, {
    cat(Debug$userCount)
    user <- paste0("user", Debug$UserCount)
    Debug$UserCount <<-  Debug$UserCount -1
})

if(user=="user3") cat( file=stderr(), user, " Working Now\n")
```

### Other Methods

With Authorized access for ShinyServerPro, I can just use

```
user <- session$user
```

For small numbers of users, I can just resample a userID when I refresh the page

```
user <- paste0("user", sample(1:2,1))
```